# Show that in $L^2[-1,1]$ the set of functions s.t $f(t)=f(t-1)$ for $t \in (0,1)$ is closed and its complement is $g(t)=-g(t-1)$ for $t \in (0,1)$

Tags: functional-analysis

Show that in $L^2[-1,1]$ the set of functions s.t $f(t)=f(t-1)$ for $t \in (0,1)$ is closed and its orthogonal complement is functions satisfying  $g(t)=-g(t-1)$ for $t \in (0,1)$

My solution:

To show the space of such $f$ is closed is standard, you have a sub sequence that converges a.e and then  the relation is preserved by a.e convergence and so the set is closed. It is also fairly easy to show that functions like $g$ are in the orthogonal complement. What i have trouble is showing that these are all such functions. What I did: I tried to decompose an arbitrary function $h$ into two parts $f+g$ where $f$ is of the first kind and $g$ is of the second kind. I got $f(x)=\frac{\chi_{[0,1]}h(x)+\chi_{[-1,0]}h(x+1)}{2}$ But i do not think this is correct as $h(x)-f(x)=g(x)$ is not of the second kind.

How to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(t)=f(t-1)$ a.e on $(0,1)$ iff $\int_0^{1} [f(t)-f(t-1)]h(t)dt=0$ for all $h \in L^{2}[0,1]$. Now $\int_0^{1} [f(t)-f(t-1)]h(t)=\int_0^{1} f(s)[h(s)1_{(0,1)}-h(s+1)1_{(-1,0)}]ds=0$. Thus  the given set is the orthogonal complement of $\{h(s)1_{(0,1)}-h(s+1)1_{(-1,0)}: h \in L^{2}[0,1]\}$. It is quite easy to check an $L^{2}$ function $g$ has the form $h(s)1_{(0,1)}-h(s+1)1_{(-1,1)}$ iff $g(t)=-g(t-1)$ a.e. on $(0,1)$.